# Sensors temp1 to temp10 real names?

Tags: laptop, hp, temperature, sensors, lm-sensors

So my computer becomes a bit hot sometimes and using sensors I get this:

```
temp1:         +0.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)
temp2:        +49.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)
temp3:        +11.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp4:        +47.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)
temp5:         +0.0°C  (crit = +115.0°C)
temp6:        +32.2°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp7:         +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp8:        +45.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp9:        +49.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp10:       +59.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +46.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:       +44.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

I see that temp10 is a little high but I have no clue what it is.

How can I identify those sensors?

Thanks!